# What is the parameter name for basic authentication in meteor's http.post API?

Tags: meteor

I'm using HTTP.post in meteor and I need to send basic authentication with only a username to an external service. Where does this go and what would that look like?

I am only using it on the server side so I know it should look like the below code, but I'm not sure where to put the username and what to call it.

I've tried this.

```
var resultSet = HTTP.post("https://billy.balancedpayments.com/v1/customers", {
    params: {"processor_uri": "/customers/customerURI"},
    authentication: {"MYKEYHERE":""}
});
```

And this.

```
var resultSet = HTTP.post("https://billy.balancedpayments.com/v1/customers", {
    params: {"authentication": "MYKEYHERE",
    "processor_uri": "/customers/customerURI"}
});
```

And this.

```
var resultSet = HTTP.post("https://billy.balancedpayments.com/v1/customers", {
    params: {"processor_uri": "/customers/customerURI"
    },
    headers: {'Authorization': 'MYKEYHERE'}
});
```

I get this error each time.

```
Error: failed [403] 403 Forbidden  Access was denied to this resource. 
Unauthorized: CustomerIndexView failed permission check
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plain `auth : 'username:password'` should do (from [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call)):

```
var resultSet = HTTP.post("https://billy.balancedpayments.com/v1/customers", {
    params: {"processor_uri": "/customers/customerURI"},
    auth: 'yourkey:'
});
```

As per the balanced payments documentation:

> To authenticate with Balanced, you will need the API key secret provided from the dashboard. You have to use http basic access authentication. Your key has to be set as the username. A password is not required for simplicity.

So this means you leave the password blank, so its just your key followed by the colon `:`

Also you might want to consider using the [balanced package](http://atmospherejs.com/package/balanced-payments) for Meteor which does all the boilerplate for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to add a comma after the params section ```params: {...},```